# How to extract text from a Word doc / docx and perform logic using PHP

Tags: php, laravel, docx, doc

My goal is to read the uploaded document and extract certain values like floats "1.20, 3.9", text.
I have tried a few libraries, but nothing seems to get the job done.

Also, the files will contain tables like structure most of the time which spits out the vertical lines of the borders as well.

What comes to mind is some heavy regex parsing logic...

Anyone with a suggestable solution ?

Comment: Maybe you should use an online tool such as CloudConvert to transform the doc/docx file (can't be parsed in PHP) to a simple TXT file (easily parsed with regex etc.). There's a simple API to access CC functionnalities, I'm using it. That's a pity you have to do stuff with a doc/docx document (not a text format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For docx file, you can try this

```
 $zip = zip_open($file);

                if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;

                while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {

                    if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;

                    if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;

                    $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));
                    zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
                } // end while

                zip_close($zip);
```

It will extract the DOCX document into text, because you can't get with only using `file_get_content` from php

And for DOC file

```
if (($fh = fopen($file, 'rb')) !== false) {
                $headers = fread($fh, 0xA00);

                // read doc from 0 to 255 characters
                $n1 = (ord($headers[0x21C]) - 1);

                // read doc from 256 to 63743 characters
                $n2 = ((ord($headers[0x21D]) - 8) * 256);

                // read doc from 63744 to 16775423 characters
                $n3 = ((ord($headers[0x21E]) * 256) * 256);

                //read doc from 16775424 to 4294965504 characters
                $n4 = (((ord($headers[0x21F]) * 256) * 256) * 256);

                // Total length of text in the document
                $textLength = ($n1 + $n2 + $n3 + $n4);
                ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
                $extracted_plaintext = fread($fh, $textLength);
            }
```

After you convert it to text, times to crawl your desired text to using **REGEX**